# fatal - AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid config values: fastRefresh

Tags: node.js, typescript, yarnpkg, umi

when I using this command to build the project in GitHub Actions:

```
yarn
yarn global add umi
umi build
```

shows error like this:

```
warning "umi > @umijs/lint > eslint-plugin-jest > @typescript-eslint/utils > eslint-utils@3.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=5".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "umi@4.0.5" with binaries:
      - umi
Done in 16.72s.
fatal - AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid config values: fastRefresh
Invalid value for fastRefresh:
"value" must be a boolean
    at Function.validateConfig (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@umijs/core/dist/config/config.js:154:30)
    at Config.getConfig (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@umijs/core/dist/config/config.js:38:16)
    at Service.resolveConfig (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@umijs/core/dist/service/service.js:301:38)
    at Service.run (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/@umijs/core/dist/service/service.js:233:54)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Service.run2 (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/umi/dist/service/service.js:36:16)
    at async Object.run (/home/runner/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/umi/dist/cli/cli.js:37:13) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
fatal - A complete log of this run can be found in:
fatal - /home/runner/work/react-admin/react-admin/node_modules/.cache/logger/umi.log
fatal - Consider reporting a GitHub issue on https://github.com/umijs/umi/issues
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

why did this happen? this is the github actions script:

```
     name: management-system-pro-umi

on:
  push:
    branches: [ umi ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm install yarn -g
      - name: Build React App
        run: | 
          yarn
          yarn global add umi
          umi build

      - name: Build image push to aliyun
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
          tags: ${{ github.sha }}
          repository: reddwarf-pro/react-admin-new
          path: '.'
    
       # https://github.com/steebchen/kubectl
      - name: deploy to cluster
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          command: set image --record deployment/react-admin-new react-admin-new=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/react-admin-new:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro

      - name: verify deployment
        uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
        with:
          config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
          version: v1.21.0 # specify kubectl binary version explicitly
          command: rollout status deployment/react-admin-new -n reddwarf-pro
```

and this is the package json:

```
{
  "name": "ant-design-pro",
  "version": "5.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "An out-of-box UI solution for enterprise applications",
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=1 umi build",
    "build": "umi build",
    "deploy": "npm run build && npm run gh-pages",
    "dev": "npm run start:dev",
    "gh-pages": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "i18n-remove": "pro i18n-remove --locale=zh-CN --write",
    "postinstall": "umi g tmp",
    "lint": "umi g tmp && npm run lint:js && npm run lint:style && npm run lint:prettier && npm run tsc",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "lint-staged:js": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --cache --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --format=pretty ./src && npm run lint:style",
    "lint:js": "eslint --cache --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --format=pretty ./src",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier -c --write \"src/**/*\" --end-of-line auto",
    "lint:style": "stylelint --fix \"src/**/*.less\" --syntax less",
    "openapi": "umi openapi",
    "playwright": "playwright install && playwright test",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "prettier": "prettier -c --write \"src/**/*\"",
    "serve": "umi-serve",
    "start": "cross-env UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "start:dev": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=dev MOCK=none UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "start:no-mock": "cross-env MOCK=none UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "start:no-ui": "cross-env UMI_UI=none UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "start:pre": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=pre UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "start:test": "cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=test MOCK=none UMI_ENV=dev umi dev",
    "test": "umi test",
    "test:component": "umi test ./src/components",
    "test:e2e": "node ./tests/run-tests.js",
    "tsc": "tsc --noEmit"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.less": "stylelint --syntax less",
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "npm run lint-staged:js",
    "**/*.{js,jsx,tsx,ts,less,md,json}": [
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 10"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.7.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-descriptions": "^1.10.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-form": "^1.52.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-layout": "^6.32.0",
    "@ant-design/pro-table": "2.72.1",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/react-loadable": "^5.5.6",
    "@umijs/route-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "antd": "^4.17.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.1",
    "js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
    "lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "omit.js": "^2.0.2",
    "rc-menu": "^9.1.0",
    "rc-util": "^5.16.0",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dev-inspector": "^1.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.2.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-native-aes-crypto": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "umi": "^3.5.0",
    "umi-request": "^1.4.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ant-design/pro-cli": "^2.1.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.18",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@umijs/fabric": "^2.8.0",
    "@umijs/openapi": "^1.3.0",
    "@umijs/plugin-blocks": "^2.2.0",
    "@umijs/plugin-esbuild": "^1.4.0",
    "@umijs/plugin-openapi": "^1.3.0",
    "@umijs/preset-ant-design-pro": "^1.3.0",
    "@umijs/preset-dumi": "^1.1.0",
    "@umijs/preset-react": "^1.8.17",
    "@umijs/yorkie": "^2.0.5",
    "carlo": "^0.9.46",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.0",
    "cross-port-killer": "^1.3.0",
    "detect-installer": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.0",
    "jsdom-global": "^3.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.0.0",
    "mockjs": "^1.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.0",
    "puppeteer-core": "^8.0.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-react": "^3.52.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.0",
    "umi-serve": "^1.9.10"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10.0.0"
  },
  "gitHooks": {
    "commit-msg": "fabric verify-commit"
  }
}
```

in my local macbook pro, it works fine, but when compile using github actions, shows error like that. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? this node version is 16.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config.ts` there will be a property called `fastRefresh: {}` change that to `fastRefresh: true/false`